# Wordpress Template - "Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress and while writing a new post, i'm getting a following error in place of the optional boxes, located below the writing area:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could
>   not be converted to string in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions/meta-boxes.php
>   on line 466

I've pasted a the problem code below taken from meta-boxes.php

Also, below, i've commented on the 466th line of code to let you know where the point if error is:

```
 <?php  
    // get review-specific meta fields
    global $oswcPostTypes; 
    $postTypeId = get_post_type( $post->ID );   
    $postType = $oswcPostTypes->get_type_by_id($postTypeId);
    $meta_fields = $postType->meta_fields;
    foreach($meta_fields as $meta){
        //make backwards compatible
        if(is_object($meta)){
            $metaName = $meta->name;
        }else{
            $metaName = $meta;
        }
        $metaNameSafe = str_replace(" ","_",$metaName); // **466th line of error**
        $theMeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $metaName, $single = true); ?>      
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $metaNameSafe; ?>"><?php echo $metaName; ?></label> </td>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $metaNameSafe; ?>" name="<?php echo $metaNameSafe; ?>"><?php echo $theMeta; ?></textarea>
        </p>

    <?php
```

Answer (score 0):

I think $meta->name is object. try : print_r( $meta->name ).

OR

I think it should be:
$metaName = $meta->labels->name

Not tested though.

Thanks